# How to kill a range of consecutive processes in Linux?

Tags: linux, shell, kill

I am working on a multi-user Ubuntu server and need to run multiprocessing python scripts. Sometimes I need to kill some of those processes. For example,

```
$ ps -eo pid,comm,cmd,start,etime | grep .py
3457 python          python process_to_kill.py - 20:57:28    01:44:09
3458 python          python process_to_kill.py - 20:57:28    01:44:09
3459 python          python process_to_kill.py - 20:57:28    01:44:09
3460 python          python process_to_kill.py - 20:57:28    01:44:09
3461 python          python process_to_kill.py - 20:57:28    01:44:09
3462 python          python process_to_kill.py - 20:57:28    01:44:09
3463 python          python process_to_kill.py - 20:57:28    01:44:09
3464 python          python process_to_kill.py - 20:57:28    01:44:09
13465 python         python process_not_to_kill.py - 08:57:28    13:44:09
13466 python         python process_not_to_kill.py - 08:57:28    13:44:09
```

processes 3457-3464 are to be killed. So far I can only do

```
$ kill 3457 3458 3459 3460 3461 3462 3463 3464
```

Is there a command like `$ kill 3457-3464` so I can specify the starting and ending processes and kill all of those within the range?

Comment: `ps -H` will tell you whether they are related; you might prefer to kill the process group in that cales (e.g. `kill -3457`).

Answer (score 53, accepted):

Use the shell's brace expansion syntax:

```
$ kill {3457..3464}
```

which expands to:

```
$ kill 3457 3458 3459 3460 3461 3462 3463 3464
```

Or you can kill processes by name with `pkill`. For example:

```
$ pkill -f process_to_kill.py
```