# Parallel tasks not removed after stopping cluster

Tags: r, parallel-processing, parallel.foreach, doparallel

After running and stopping a parallel process, workers still appear to be running on my system and taking up resources. I know processes belong to parallel because they are the same number as the cores I had set up originally, and because upon inspecting in the system monitor, there are references to parallel. It seems like every time I go through my foreach loop, these processes accumulate and eventually slow down my system. Is there any programmatic way to get rid of them?

My code is basic, and I've tried doParallel, doFuture, and doSNOW.

Using Linux Mint Cinnamon OS here for development, and running in an HPC node using Linux where performance is much less than expected and I am showing that memory usage is much higher than CPU usage. My hunch is that these processes on my dev machine are the same thing that is slowing down the HPC.There should be no memory remaining after each foreach loop, so in my mind memory usage should be every efficient.

```
library(doFuture)
library(foreach)

my.cl <- parallelly::makeClusterPSOCK(n_cores, autoStop = TRUE)
doParallel::registerDoParallel(cl = my.cl, cores = n_cores)

foreach(...) %dofuture% {...}

parallel::stopCluster(cl = my.cl)
```

[image]

Comment: `my.cl` vs `my.cluster`.

Comment: As @Roland noted rule out you stopping the wrong cluster. Apparently you're working on an unix-alike system, OS information should always be added with such issues. Anyway,  when I experience similar issues, I check `htop`, sort by PID, and kill the range of corresponding processes, e.g. [`kill -9 {20310..20320}`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49756921/6574038). Maybe the code failed and therefore ghost processes; try using [`on.exit(stopCluster(cl))`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41679580/6574038), but I think this just happens from time to time.

Comment: Thanks Roland and @jay.sf. I edited the post for clarity. The my.cl and my.cluster was my late-night sloppiness, so is not the issue. I have the correct variable set-up in the actual code. Since I am running this as a foreach loop, I can't use the suggested kill or on.exit(stopCluster(cl)) until the foreach is done running. The issue is that these ghost processes accumulate after each loop and bog down my memory.

Comment: @APD Admittedly FORKer, so neither Future nor PSOCK user. But you might want to post something reproducible.

Comment: FYI, using `%dofuture%` should go with a `future::plan(...)` setup. If you use `%dopar%`, then you need that `doParallel::registerDoParallel()`. But don't mix and match. Pick one of them. If you actually use the above example code as-is, then there is nothing running in parallel, because the default is `plan(sequential)`; you're basically just creating a cluster, registering it with **doParallel**, which is never used, and stops the cluster at the end.